# Move all Android development directories into single directory on Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio

By default Android Studio and related Android development tools create many different directories in $HOME directory: .android, .AndroidStudio4.0, .gradle and .java .
My goal is to move them all into single directory $HOME/Android/ and keep $HOME directory clean. So far I've set following exports in .bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=$HOME/Android/
export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$HOME/Android/.gradle
```

And custom paths in idea.properties:

```
idea.config.path=${user.home}/Android/.AndroidStudio4.0/config
idea.system.path=${user.home}/Android/.AndroidStudio4.0/system
```

While bigger files end up in new directory, still .android, .AndroidStudio4.0, .gradle and .java directories are re-created in $HOME directory, some even have files. Is there any way to prevent AndroidStudio creating those directories and messing up my $HOME?

Comment: I am also trying to do the same thing.  even setting gradle home in android studio home doesn't seem to help.  I was able to move the sdk, and did the same thing  you've done for config & system.  but it still keeps everything.  I even tried following: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32759785/317027 but no luck.  If you figure it out pls post your approach

Comment: Found some hints in ArchLinux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory (java, adb), but still some directories just refuse to move from home and are recreated each time I start Android Studio.